# Autoloading Rails models that don't follow the default file name structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, autoload

THE SHORT VERSION: How do I tell Rails to autoload an ActiveRecord class called `ClassName` that isn't located in the default location (`app/models/class_name.rb`). E.g. what if it's in `app/models/subdirectory/class_name.rb` and I don't want to rename the class to `Subdirectory::ClassName`?

THE LONGER VERSION:

I know that, by default in Rails, my class names have to follow a specific structure for Rails to be able to autoload them.

E.g. If my class is called `Person`, if I put it in `app/models/person.rb`, Rails can load it fine, but if I put it in e.g. `app/models/person_class.rb`, it can't. If I namespace it, e.g. `Humanity::Person`, I need to put it in the right folder `app/model/humanity/person`.

(Plus I can put classes in `lib` but I'll leave aside that detail for now)

So far so good. But what happens when I have a ton of ActiveRecord classes clogging up my `app/models` folder and I want to logically organise them into directory, but don't want to rename or namespace the actual classes? How can I tell Rails to autoload this classes?

Or is there a good reason why I shouldn't do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**/}')]
```

Then you can use your model with their name as it is without name-spacing.

Comment: restart the server after adding above line

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason why it might be bad idea to override the Rails defaults in this way?

Comment: I don't think its a bad idea, you are just tweaking it as per your need.